# Send email from app with firebase functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I want to now if its possible to send e-mail using firebase triger mail from the App with callable functions. I want to be able to call the function and in that function i want to send email or/ i want to use the extention of firebase "triger mail". I have tried this but nothing happens

```
exports.sendEmail = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
return admin.firestore().collection('mail').add({
    to: data,
    message: {
      subject: 'Hello from Firebase!',
      html: 'This is an <code>HTML</code> email body.',
    },
  })
```

})

and in my function i call the function as

```
sendmail() {
  let send = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('sendEmail')
  send({mail:'v@x.com'})
},
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible from any sort of Cloud Function.  If you're having problems with that, please post your code that isn't working the way you expect, along with any error messages you find in the log.  We should be able to duplicate the issue from what you provide.

Comment: There is even a Firebase Extension for this precise use-case: https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firestore-send-email